# Typing an arrow function parameters

Tags: typescript

This is my typed function.

```
const setupFn = (
  sdkToken: ITokenResponse["kycToken"],
  onDocSubmit: (data: any) => void,
  kycStatuses: IKYCStatuses,
  setKycStatuses: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<IKYCStatuses>>,
  setModalClosed: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>,
  handleError: (e: any) => void,
) => {}
```

**Usage**:

```
setupFn(
   res.data?.kycToken,
   onDocSubmit,
   kycStatuses,
   setKycStatuses,
   setModalClosed,
   handleError,
)
```

I was wondering how can I extract the type declaration outside of the function in an interface.

**My attempt so far:**

```
interface IProps {
      sdkToken: ITokenResponse["kycToken"];
      onDocSubmit: (data: any) => void;
      kycStatuses: IKYCStatuses;
      setKycStatuses: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<IKYCStatuses>>;
      setModalClosed: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
      handleError: (e: any) => void;
}
const setupFn = (
      {sdkToken,
      onDocSubmit,
      kycStatuses,
      setKycStatuses,
      setModalClosed,
      handleError}: IProps
    ) => {}
```

**Usage:**

```
setupFn({
          sdkToken: res.data?.kycToken,
          onDocSubmit,
          kycStatuses,
          setKycStatuses,
          setModalClosed,
          handleError,
        })
```

**Question:**
Is it possible to extract the type outside of function but without changing the parameter to an object so that I don't have to update the usage of the setupFn everywhere.

What would be your ideal way of typing the `setupFn` mentioned here.

Comment: You cannot set the types for a variety of variables in one statement, when the variables are separate from one another. However, you may be able to put a type on the const variable instead.

Comment: You can simply do: `const setupFn = (props: IProps) => {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, if this is what you're asking for, but you can use Parameters to extract a tuple of function parameters, like this [Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmUCuAHAYmGBeGAKAUDHACYDWAKiKfGAFwwAiAhlPADSEzgMjADKSAEYBbAJZR6uYiyb0mYAJ4BKbAD4YANxCjiHIqQX8oLJAgj1oAJ1FgA5nriIA0ob7HkZ%20mCTDB8S-gqWOoA3gC%20%20PhQCijwMHyIqBgACkyWTMIQ2DCp6cKI-hAAPNGxIABmjsjoYKoA3JH4oJCwCNW5GebxiTUdmdkA2mDwAO6MLPC4Smx4QeoAjDMA5AZGJmZLMwAsAEwAug34bUlguAB0F8cofRBKQA):

```js
const setupFn = (
  sdkToken: Date,
  onDocSubmit: (data: any) => void,
  kycStatuses: string,
  setKycStatuses: number
) => {}

type SetupFnParams = Parameters<typeof setupFn>;


const setupParams: SetupFnParams = [new Date(), () => 1, 'kycStatuses', 42];

setupFn(...setupParams)
```

Comment: Thanks. Although it's not what I was looking for. It's interesting to see your approach.

I was curious if there is a way to remove typing for individual params on function declaration ex: the function will be as such but the types can be declared outside and just pass with a single type

`const setupFn = (
  sdkToken,
  onDocSubmit,
  kycStatuses,
  setKycStatuses
) => {}`

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to do that.

Comment: you should try to better describe what you try to do - maybe with types-script playground code or some pseudo-code examples,